# Pandas to_excel is overriding values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create an excel report using pandas.df.to_excel() method. Here is my snippet.

```
r2 = [183, 143]

for item in r2:
    cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
    row3 = cursor.fetchall()
    thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]
    r3 += list(map(int, thi_tuple))
    print(r3)
    df2 = DataFrame({'CMS_ID': item, 'version': r3})
    writer2 = ExcelWriter(join(sep, "C:" + sep, "MyCave" + sep, "iso" + sep, "SDG" + sep, "Int" + sep, "latest" + sep, "other_dependencies.xlsx"), engine = 'xlsxwriter')
    df2.to_excel(writer2, sheet_name = 'other dependencies', startrow=1, header=False )
    workbook  = writer2.book
    worksheet = writer2.sheets['other dependencies']
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value)
     writer2.save()
```

It is writing to excel sheet.

Instead of printing both items of r2 to excel, it is just printing 143.

How to resolve the logic?

Regards

Comment: why are you using a loop? first you write 183 in the file and then you overwrite it with 143

Comment: @luigigi i have updated the code snippet. That's the reason why I am looping. I want to print two columns in excel sheet. Write the case id and the number of versions it has. For example, Case ID 183 will have v1, v2, v3, etc and case 183 will have v1 and v2. It must print all these things in excel. It is printing all versions correctly, but it is printing only one case id due to the looping

Comment: you should create the full DataFrame first like you want it in the excel file (you can use a loop for this) and after write it to excel

Comment: @luigigi Hi...I am pretty new to pandas. I feel like I did exactly you had said in the comment. I request you to point out the error.

Comment: you are writing in the loop, but you shouldn't. move the whole writing part out of the loop. you should create the FULL dataframe (print it so you are sure it is like it should to be) and after you write it to an excel file (NOT as a loop). you write the dataframe as a whole in the file

Comment: Where does `join` come from in your code? It doesn't look like [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`String.join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm).

Comment: @Brian it is os.path.join()

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to this:

```
r2 = [183, 143]

writer2 = ExcelWriter(os.path.join(sep, "tmp" + sep, "other_dependencies.xlsx"), engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for i in range(0, len(r2)):
    item = r2[i]  # the item here is equal to the item in "for item in r2:"
    cursor.execute('select distinct Version_Num from dbo.test where CMS_ID = ? and deployment_status = 0', item)
    row3 = cursor.fetchall()
    thi_tuple = [c_tup[0] for c_tup in row3]
    r3 += list(map(int, thi_tuple))
    print(r3)
    df2 = DataFrame({'CMS_ID': item, 'version': r3})
    df2.to_excel(writer2, sheet_name = 'other dependencies', startrow=i+1, header=False )
    workbook  = writer2.book
    worksheet = writer2.sheets['other dependencies']
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value)
writer2.save()
```

I moved the creation of the excel file to the outside of the for loop. And I also changed the `startrow` to a variable `i`.

`i` determines which row to write to.

`startrow` starts from `1`, while the index of `r2` starts from `0`. This is why I write `i+1` for `startrow`.